# Kubuntu 18.04 KDE Plasma Headset Microphone marked as "unplugged" until manually selected

Tags: audio, kde, kubuntu, pulse-audio, headset

When connecting a headset with a combined audio+microphone 4 pole connector to my laptop (XPS 15 9570), I cannot get KDE to automatically switch to the headset microphone. When connecting the headset, KDE seems to not register the headset microphone, and denotes it as "Headset Microphone (unplugged)" under the capture device audio settings ports selection.

As soon as I click the "Headset Microhpne (unplugged)", the "unplugged" part gets immediately removed from the UI, and the headset microphone works as expected.

The three attached images shows 1) the KDE audio settings when no headset is plugged in, 2) the audio settings when the headset is plugged in, and 3) the audio settings after I manually switch to "Headset Microphone (unplugged)".

I should also note that I'm using the "Analouge Stero Duplex" profile for the Built-in Audio device, and have checked the "Automatically switch all running streams when a new output becomes available" checkbox.

How do I get KDE to automatically detect/switch to the headset microphone when the headset is plugged in, just as it does for the output?

**Image 1: No headset plugged in:**

### [image: No headset plugged in]

**Image 2: Headset plugged in (default options):**

### [image: Headset plugged in]

**Image 3: Headset plugged in, Headset Microphone manually selected:**

[image: Headset Microphone manually selected]